# Insertion of data in column separatly - Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a **user** table in mysql database with column name **"id" and "name".** And i want to insert data in columns separatly.

I am inserting data into first column successfully with following command.

```
insert into user(id) values (1),(2),(3);

select * from user;

+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | NULL |
|    2 | NULL |
|    3 | NULL |
+------+------+
```

Inserting values in second column like.

```
insert into user(name) values ('abc'),('def'),('xyz');
```

i am getting result.

```
select * from user;

+------+--------+
| id   | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | NULL   |
|    2 | NULL   |
|    3 | NULL   |
| NULL | abc    |
| NULL | def    |
| NULL | xyz    |
+------+--------+
```

I want a solution which make me able to insert values in names column from 0 index. and result should look like this but with separate insertion in column.

```
+------+--------+
| id   | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | abc    |
|    2 | def    |
|    3 | xyz    |
```

Comment: this is not an `insert` operation, but `update`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `insert` statement to insert new rows and `update` statement to update existing:

```
update user set name = 'abc' where id = 1;
```

or for your case

```
update mytable
    set name = case id
        when 1 then 'abc'
        when 2 then 'def'
        when 3 then 'xyz'
    end
where id in (1,2,3)
```

or if your `id` is primary key, you can use `insert ... on duplicate key update` statement:

```
 insert into user (id, name) 
   values (1, 'abc'), (2, 'def'), (3, 'xyz')
       on duplicate key 
   update name = values(name);
```

sample:

```
mysql> create table user (id int(11) primary key, name varchar(10) null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.27 sec)

mysql> insert into user (id) values (1),(2),(3);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql>      insert into user (id, name)
    ->        values (1, 'abc'), (2, 'def'), (3, 'xyz')
    ->            on duplicate key
    ->        update name = values(name);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from user;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | abc  |
|  2 | def  |
|  3 | xyz  |
+----+------+
```

Comment: If i am inserting thousand rows by using "Mysql for Excel" in excel to mysql table, it will take time, is there any other solution??

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting means adding one row,, but you want to update,, so use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`

```
UPDATE user SET name = 'abc' WHERE id = 1;
```